# Despite using the same function. it behaves incorrectly one time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following code, its for a basic top down shooter similar to space invaders. When the player's bullets hit the enemy, the enemy follows the various hit functions correctly and flashes invisible for a third of a second. however when the player gets hit he seems to permanently turn invisible despite using the same functions. Any ideas as to why this happens and where I'm going wrong? My code may be considered messy by those of you with experience so please by all means criticize as much as you can :P The structure and process behind the code makes sense in my mind but if anyone is struggling feel free to ask "wtf are you doing" :P

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;


public class Level1 extends MovieClip {

    public var player:Player; // play
    public var upgrade:blue_wep;
    public var enemy1:fly; // first enemy used for testing

    public var enemyList:Array = [];    // Array similar to bullets but for each enemy

    public var LevelTimer:Timer; // creating a game timer used to see how long the player survived

    public var upgraded:Boolean = false;

    //Code for shooting bullets
    public var bulletList:Array = []; //This array simply contains information for each bullet
    public var enemyBullets:Array = [];
    public var mousePressed:Boolean = false; //boolean similar to player movement but this checks if the mouse button is pressed
    public var weaponSpeed:Number = 1; // This is an amplifier to modify the player's shooting speed when collecting powerups
    public var delayCounter:int = 0; //used to create delay between shots
    public var delayMax:Number = 10 * weaponSpeed; //This is the number that defines how quickly we can shoot

    //The following variables are for when the fly gets hit by a bullet
    public var losingHealth:Boolean = false;
    public var hitTimer:int;
    public var deathTimer:int;
    public var hurt:Boolean = false;
    public var deathFlash:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform;

    public function Level1() {
        // constructor code
        player = new Player(stage, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, 100, 100, 10);
        stage.addChild(player);

        upgrade = new blue_wep(stage, stage.stageWidth/6, stage.stageHeight/2, 5);

        enemy1 = new fly(stage, (Math.random() * stage.stageWidth), (Math.random() * stage.stageHeight), player, 100, 100, 20);
        stage.addChild(enemy1);

        LevelTimer = new Timer(1000);

        hitTimer = 0;
        deathTimer = 0;
        deathFlash.color = 0xFFFFFF;

                                                                               // is clicked. This works for single fire
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

    }
    public function loop(e:Event):void { // this function is the loop for adding bullets that move

        if(mousePressed) {
            delayCounter++
            if (delayCounter == delayMax) {
                PlayershootBullet();
                delayCounter = 0;
            }
        }

        if (bulletList.length > 0) { //if there are any bullets on the screen we are going to execute the following code
            for (var i:int = 0; i < bulletList.length; i++) { //the following code will be executed on each bullet
                bulletList[i].loop(); // we are going to use the loop function found in the bullet class file on each bullet
            }

        }

        enemyBullets = enemy1.bulletList;

        collisionCheck(bulletList, player, enemy1);
        if (losingHealth == true) {
            healthLoss(player, enemy1);
        }
        else {
            losingHealth = false;
        collisionCheck(enemyBullets, enemy1, player);
        if (losingHealth == true) {
            healthLoss(enemy1, player);
        }
    }
        }


    public function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        mousePressed = true;
    }

    public function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        mousePressed = false;
    }

    public function removeUpgrade():void {
        stage.removeChild(upgrade);
    }
    public function PlayershootBullet():void {
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(stage, player.x, player.y, player.rotation, false);
        bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved, false, 0, true); //if the bullet goes off the stage
                                                                                          // we will call the bulletremoved function
        bulletList.push(bullet); // add this bullet to the current list
        stage.addChild(bullet);
    }

    public function bulletRemoved(e:Event):void {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved); // remove the listener to stop errors
        bulletList.splice(bulletList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1); // remove the bullet thats off the stage from the array
    }

    public function takeHit(wounded, shooter) {
        wounded.life -= shooter.dmg;
        wounded.healthratio = (wounded.life/wounded.maxLife) * 100;
        trace(wounded.healthratio);

    }

    public function enemyFlash(flasher, shooter) {
        flasher.alpha = 0;
        if (hurt == false) {
            takeHit(flasher, shooter);
        }
    }

    public function hitReset(hostile) {
        trace("hitReset");
        hitTimer = 0;
        losingHealth = false;
        hurt = false;
        hostile.alpha = 1;
    }

    public function removeEnemy(cya) {
        deathTimer = 0;
        cya.removeSelf();
        for (var i = 0; i < bulletList.length;i++) {
            bulletList[i].x = stage.stageWidth + 100;
        }
    }

    public function collisionCheck(bullets, shooter, target) {
        for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
            if (bullets[i].hitTestObject(target)) {
                //bulletList[i].has_hit = true;
                bullets[i].x = stage.stageWidth + 100;
                bullets[i].y = stage.stageHeight + 100;
                losingHealth = true;
                }
            }

            if (target.healthratio <= 0) {
                removeEnemy(target);
            }
    }

    public function healthLoss(shooter, target) {
        hitTimer++;
        if (hitTimer < 10) {
            enemyFlash(target, shooter);
            hurt = true;
        }
        else {
            hitReset(target);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely your problem comes from the single boolean losingHealth that you are using for everything. That boolean can only have 2 values but you use it fro all your enemies and player. It's impossible for that single boolean to keep track of all enemies and player state. What you probably should have is one boolean for each enemies and player.

Comment: That seems appropriate, but I thought I reset that boolean in my functions, not only this, since I wanted to add more than the one enemy and store them all in an array would my losingHealth boolean need to be a variable in the separate class files then so I can access it like a property? (ie player.losingHealth = true)

Comment: Yes that's what you should do. Right now that variable can be set to false or true for an object and then immediately set to something else for another. Yet you use it to check on all object state but that's never gonna work.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll give it a try now and see how it works out for me :)